# Favicon Editor, Not Working

Tags: image, web, favicon

So I see people with great high quality Favicons, but yet mine looks like a piece of crap. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Photoshop it, then keep it in a local directory.

Comment: hmmm, alright I guess that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally photoshop my images and include them in the page assets:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
```

Rather than dynamically letting a browser resize it managing the icon size myself seems easier, plus there's less bandwidth involved on the page load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Axialis icon workshop** for make best .ico icons for webiste in 16px x 16px size or you can use the png icon also in 16px x 16px image for fav icon